# Java string formatting issue

Tags: java, string

```
while(count <= maxNum){
     System.out.println("O-------O");
     System.out.printf("|" + "%8s", count + "|");
     System.out.println("O-------O");
     count++;
     startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
     //an empty loop! does nothing except keeps checking the continuation condition
     //continues as long as the time that has passed is less than millisToWait
     while(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime < millisToWait);
  System.out.println("O-------O");
```

Above is the part of code that conecerns the actual output of what I am trying to achieve. The code, for the most part works as intended, except the output(below is the output attached as an image) is not 100% correct. There is an extra "O-------O" to the right of every number.

[Here's the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7sj4.png)

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe it has something to do with the first println statement, but I'm still not sure how it's printing once on top and then once to the side. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printf doesn't automaticly add a newline, you have to do that manually by adding a newline character into the string. We use %n instaid of \n for portability reasons. The format can also be simplified.

Change the third line to:

```
System.out.printf("|%8s%n|", count);
```

Comment: Wow. That one modification fixed it. Thank you so much.

Comment: @shmosel Thanks, I added it into the answer.